# Unable to deploy firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to deploy a firebase cloud function. It works on local firebase emulator but when I try to deploy, it's giving the following error on firebase console cloud functions log:
`{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":13,"message":"Failed to configure trigger for event-type:providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.update resource:projects/kapsule-1099e/databases/(default)/documents/roles/warehouser/{warehouseName}/{warehouseName}/Inventory/{assetName} service:firestore.googleapis.com."},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"malickfaizann@gmail.com"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/kapsule-1099e/locations/us-central1/functions/sendNotificationOnLowStock"}`

Comment: Can you share the code so we can see the path for trigger? The error says path is `/{warehouseName}/{warehouseName}`. Try changing variable name of either 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. Path params cannot have same name even if their values are same. I renamed one of them and it worked.
Final path is:

```
roles/warehouser/{warehouseName}/{warehouseName2}/Inventory/{assetName}
```